# Must declare the scalar variable - Why isn't my parameter recognized?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework to send a query to the database using `ExecuteStoreQuery`

```
If (DBEntity.ExecuteStoreQuery(Of Integer)("SELECT COUNT(ReceiptUID) FROM qryRptSrc_Cust_GoodsReceipt_Issues WHERE ReceiptUID = @Recpt", ReceiptUID)(0) > 0) Then ....
```

Which gives me the error message that my scalar variable `@Recpt` hasn't been declared. I know what that error message means, but I'm wondering why it's being thrown in this case. `ReceiptUID` is a Guid with the correct value. The parameters that are passed don't have to be `DbParameter` objects, they can just be values and it should work fine. I've done it that was in the past before without issue, and even MSDN states

`The parameters value can be an array of DbParameter objects or an array of parameter values. If only values are supplied, an array of DbParameter objects are created based on the order of the values in the array.`

I could create a `DbParameter` object instead, but I'd like to know why this case isn't working.

Comment: Try `@p0` instead of `@Recpt`

Comment: @JeremyCook Doh, how could I have forgotten that! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Token answer:

```
Try @p0 instead of @Recpt
```